# popular and easy to use installation software recommendation

Tags: installation

i don't know if it is appropriate to ask here, but do you have any recommendation for installation software that is easy to learn and use, yet powerful.

so far, i have only tried the build-in installation that come with VS2008, do you have any recommendation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's the [Nullsoft Scriptable Install System](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) (which is open source and used by Google, Mozilla, and Intel among others) it has a [Python plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Python_Interpreter) for maximum scripting goodness. And an [Eclipse plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/EclipseNSIS_-_NSIS_plugin_for_Eclipse) (though that might not be of interest if you're a Visual Studio user).

[Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) is free, and scriptable, but not open source.

Both are powerful, and each is pretty easy to do simple things. Both are also in pretty wide use so there's quite a bit out there in the way of how-tos. NSIS even has [wizards/editors](http://hmne.sourceforge.net/) available

Answer (score 1):

You might look at [InstallJammer](http://www.installjammer.com/), totally free and open-source :

> InstallJammer features a very powerful
>   install builder with support for
>   multiple themes and a high level of
>   configurability for installers. 
>   Installers are built as single
>   executable files for easy distribution
>   over the web and handle installing
>   everything you need for your
>   application in a simple,
>   cross-platform way.

[image]

Comment: I don't spot transaction support or rollback in their feature list. So some caution may be advisable. It's bad enough that NSIS leaves junk around when the installation fails.

Comment: InstallJammer does uninstallation well enough.